# Laravel always takes me to login page

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 5's auth module for my app. However after I created the auth functions with php artisan make:auth I can only access two paths:/login and /register no matter how I add routes in the routes.php. All other paths redirect me to the login page. How can I enable users to access certain paths without logging? Thanks.

routes.php:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('/patient', 'HomeController@registerPatient');

Route::get('test', 'HomeController@index');

Route::group(array('before' =>'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('about',  array('as' => 'about','uses' => 'HomeController@about'));
}
);

Route::group(array('before' =>'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('/physician',  array('as' => 'physician','uses' => 'HomeController@registerPhysician'));
}
);
```

Comment: Check their middleware. Without the `web` middleware on the routes in Laravel 5.2, they won't have any sessions, and thus users won't be seen as logged in.

Comment: Post your routes.php and Kernel.php there

Comment: I meant that I want users to visit certain pages before they login

Comment: Check your HomeController constructor, maybe it requires login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share your controller code? i mean do you have the auth middleware in ur controller construct?

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('/', function () {
            return view('welcome');
          });
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::get('/patient', 'HomeController@registerPatient');
    Route::get('test', 'HomeController@index');
    });

Route::group(array('before' =>'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('/physician',  array('as' => 'physician','uses' => 'HomeController@registerPhysician'));
Route::get('about',  array('as' => 'about','uses' => 'HomeController@about'));
}
);
```

anyway  check ur construct method in the homecontrollerand apply the auth middlewere only to certain methods

exemple

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => [
            'about',
            'index',
        ]]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that was the correct answer. After removing the auth middleware from the constructor the app worked as I intended.Thank you